# How to list all processes in Python?

Tags: python

Is there a function can list all processes in python?

Like Bash command `ps` or Windows command `tasklist`.

However I need a function that can run on Windows and Linux.

Comment: @luoluo Please use the standard close vote or flag to indicate a duplicate, rather than formatting the comment yourself.

Comment: @luoluo No, I need a function can run on Windows and Linux. Python doesn't have it?

Comment: The `os.listdir('/proc')` is python `bulit-in`. So what do you mean by `any platform`?

Comment: @Barmar Just probably, not sure enough.

Comment: @luoluo I mean a function can run on Windows and Linux. Windows doesn't have a `'/proc'` right?

Comment: @luoluo That's why we require multiple people to vote to close. If you're wrong, it shouldn't get enough votes.

Comment: @KevinGuan There's probably no portable Python way to do it, you have to use OS-specific features.

Comment: aha, got it. @Barmar

Comment: @Kevin in the answer linked there was a mention of [psutils](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/psutil) which'll handle making the appropriate calls to the current OS.

Comment: @JonClements Hum, let me try it.

Comment: @JonClements great! `psutil.process_iter()` is so good. So how can I close this question?